Pivot data values to row
I have a pivot table from the below data. I need to write a program or develop a formula to get the data into the below format.
Data ___________________My pivot _______ Desired result
 _  _ 
A formula or a macro. Issue I'm dealing with it converting mu columns to row and under one header which have multiple values

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Just build the pivot table by the right way:

